# Save session data to database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$date['uid']            = $this->session->userdata('id');
//$date['uid']          = $this->input->post('uid');
$date['uname']          = $this->input->post('uname');
$data['title']          = $this->input->post('title');
$data['description']    = $this->input->post('desc');
$data['created']        = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I have been trying to save user id in news table where table name is uid. I have tried different methods to do so but in vain

```
$date['uid']            = $this->session->userdata('id');
```

when i try to get id using session it returns 0. and even when I try to post uid through form

```
 <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo $this->session->userdata('id');?>
```

OR

```
 <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo $_SESSION['id'];?>
```

it also saves 0 value to database

Comment: It makes no sense to make the client submit the session ID as a value in a form. You already have the session ID. You're basically giving the client the value and making the client send the same value back to yourself so that you can save it.

Comment: if I don't save uid with post than how can i check that who created new post

Comment: as I said Bro that first I trien to save data directly from session to database using 
$date['uid']            = $this->session->userdata('id');
in codeigniter controller but it alse gave 0 value

Comment: Have you tried using `session_id()`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Comment: Also, just to make sure, you're calling session_start() somewhere prior to this code, right?

Comment: when I print session like
<?php echo $_SESSION['id'];?>
or
<?php echo $this->session->userdata('id');?>
it works

Comment: I am using codeigniter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134623/discussion-between-amjad-ali-and-americanumlaut).

Answer (score 2):

Did you try like this..

Load session library in `application/config/autoload.php`.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Then

```
$data = array(
            'uid' => $this->session->userdata('id');,
            'uname' => $this->input->post('uname'),
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'description' => $this->input->post('desc'),
            'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            );

//print_r($data);
$this->db->insert('table_name',$data); //inserts into table
```